# Remove duplicate shell command

Tags: linux, shell, command, duplicates

I would like to delete all duplicate from a file with 2 columns. The criteria is only on my first column but i need to kept the second column on the output.
Example :

- Titi a
- Toto a
- Titi b
- Titi a
- Toto b
- Tata a

Expected result :

- Tata a

I m really not an expert with shell commands. I try with "uniq -u" but i can't find a way to only search duplicates on the first columns

May be an other command would be more appropriate ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may give this a try in bash:

```
$ for col1_uniq in `cat file | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -u`; do grep $col1_uniq file; done
Tata a
$
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one case here where second letter is "a".

awk '/Ta/' file

Tata a